# Need help extracting data from database into a textbox (Pascal)

Tags: sql, database, pascal

I'm new to SQL and I am currently in a bit of a pickle. I have made an SQL database (using SQLlite3 if that matters) and I have put data into the database. I am now trying to put said data into a text box, but I am unsure as to how I would do this.

I am working in Pascal, using Lazarus.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a tdbedit to your form, and connect the datafield and datasource properties. There are db example projects in Lazarus, and the wiki also has some info

Comment: It''s perhaps worth mentioning that if the text is multi-line, the OP should try using a TDBMemo, rather than a TDBEdit.